# Push an array into an array using Jquery (from a CONSTANT)

Tags: jquery, arrays, constants, push, addition

Good day,

I have an empty array in one file, and an array with data in another.  I want to push all the data from one to the other. My problem is the array is inside a CONSTANT.  The normal way to .push or .add to the array is not working.  Any help is appreciated.

File 1 - Array

```
    var CONSTANTS = {

    LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA :[], // want to add array data inside this array
     };
```

File 2 - Array

```
    var AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget = [

    ["10501","10502","10504","10505"]
    ];

 CONSTANTS.LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA.push(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget);
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have constants.

Comment: "is not working" is  very hard error to decipher. What exactly did you try? What exactly went wrong? What was the error?

Comment: Is there a reason you use all caps for your identifiers?  Javascript is generaly a camel case langauge.

Comment: are you adding file 1 after file 2? Is there any intermediate code? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: What you are looking for is basicly a way to join arrays, javascripts concat() is probably the right answer, but since the question is tagged jQuery you can have a look at [$.merge()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use:

```
CONSTANTS.LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA.push(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget[0]);
```

Comment: Sorry guys for giving enough information.  Its been a long day. :) zz I am working off existing code that does have the var CONSTANTS which contains a couple of arrays.  I am only using caps because the previous code had the identifiers in caps. I can use camelCase

Comment: @Jergason - I tried CONSTANTS.LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA.push(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget); and that didn't work.  I also tried CONSTANTS.LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA.add(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget); and that didn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying out the code but I am getting a message from my compiler saying "Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor."  I need to fix my syntax before I can test this code

Comment: This worked out fine.  I didn't realize there was another file controlling it hence why some of the solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems here

- `AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget` is a 2d array but only has a single array of values. Should probably just be a 1d array
- You are pushing an entire array as a single value instead of individually pushing the elements of the array

Try the following

```
var AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget = ["10501","10502","10504","10505"];
for (var i = 0; i < AVAILABLIE_ZIPS_Widget.length; i++) {
  CONSTANTS.LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA.push(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, have you tried?

```
CONSTANTS.LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA.push(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget[0]);
```

Comment: When testing with alert (alert(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget[0]);)  this does give me all the data within the array.  However the data does not push to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use concat instead of push

CONSTANTS.LOCATION_LOOKUP_DATA.concat(AVAILABLE_ZIPS_Widget[0]);

What you are doing with push is adding a new member to an array that is an array of arrays.

You will end up with:
[ [ ["10501","10502","10504","10505"] ] ]

Which I would guess is probably not what you are looking for.